# Computing a double integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{f(t)}{1+{(x+g(t))}^2}dt\ dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Let $f,g$ be continuous, with $f$ integrable.

How can one evaluate $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty\dfrac{f(t)}{1+{(x+g(t))}^2}dt\ dx$ ?

Any hint would be welcome.

I have not learned Funibi/Tonelli for indefinite integrals yet.

PS : To those who are voting to close as "too broad", would you mind explaining what is too broad in my question ? I am just asking for a way to evaluate the integral, or a hint that would lead me to the solution.

Comment: Changing the order of integration is always one of the first things one should look at with double integrals.

Comment: @DanielFischer Sorry, I forgot to mention that I had not learned Fubini for indefinite integrals yet. I'll try with limits, though.

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to make it take up less vertical space -- this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions. See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9730) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future questions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without changing the order of integration this will be difficult.

Comment: Try the substitution $u = x+g(t)$, $v = t$. The determinant of the Jacobian of this transformation is $1$. Although this is more or less the same thing as changing the order of integration.

Comment: @JimmyK4542: Strictly speaking, that is only "allowed" if $g$ is differentiable. But a nice idea to circumvent the "no Fubini" restriction.

Comment: I didn't vote to close but, this question is too broad in the sense that you might as well be asking for evaluating $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x,y)dxdy$. Do you at least have a specific $f,g$ in mind? Or are you only interested in whether the integral is finite?

Comment: @AlexR. It's an exercise in a sheet we never corrected in class, I re-discovered it yesterday.Since it's in an exercise, I believe there has to be some clever solution.

Comment: @AlexR.: The result will be a fixed multiple of $\int f \, dx$, i.e. independent of $g$. Thus, I think the question is much more specific than asking for $\int\int f(x,y) dx \, dy$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty\dfrac{f(t)}{1+{(x+g(t))}^2}dt~dx$

$=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty\dfrac{f(t)}{1+{(x+g(t))}^2}dx~dt$

$=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\left[f(t)\tan^{-1}(x+g(t))\right]_{-\infty}^\infty~dt$

$=\pi\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)~dt$